# How can I retrieve all 3rd level child nodes for all records in my table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have a table like so:

```
item(id, parent_id, data)
```

There are multiple data sets in the table.  Each data set has a root record where `parent_id` is set to `-1`.  Any children of the parent record have their `parent_id` record set to the id of the parent.  Any subsequent children have their `parent_id` set to that of their immediate parent.

Say I want to get all root nodes.  That's easy

```
select * from item where parent_id = -1
```

Selecting all non-parent nodes is easy too:

```
select * from item where parent_id != -1
```

**Question**

How can I select only 3rd level nodes (from all records)?  In my specific case I am trying to find is if there are any 3rd level nodes in my table, or alternatively get an affirmation that all of the non-root records in the table are 2nd level nodes.

**Bonus Question (after working with Tom's answer)**

This query returns 50,003 records:

```
SELECT
    count(L1.id)
FROM
    Item L1
WHERE
    L1.parent_id != -1;
```

This one returns 50,000 records:

```
SELECT
    count(L2.id)
FROM
    Item L1
INNER JOIN Item L2 ON L2.parent_id = L1.id
WHERE
    L1.parent_id = -1;
```

How do I isolate those 3 records to see what's going on with them?

**Note**

Bonus - turns out those 3 records were orphaned, not connected to a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only going to three levels and exactly three levels, you can simply `JOIN` down to that level:

```
SELECT
    L3.id,
    L3.parent_id,
    L3.data
FROM
    Item L1
INNER JOIN Item L2 ON L2.parent_id = L1.id
INNER JOIN Item L3 ON L3.parent_id = L2.id
WHERE
    L1.parent_id = -1
```